# Exoplayer stop not working in RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer2.x

I am using FirestorePagingAdapter for my RecyclerView.

when fragment close I try to stop exoplayer in onStop, onPasue, onDestroy method but
it not work properly, It stop only last video in Recycler view but I didn't understand
what is the main problem here.

```
   @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
        if (HomeVideoHolder.simpleExoPlayer != null) {
            HomeVideoHolder.simpleExoPlayer.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        adapter.stopListening();
        if (HomeVideoHolder.simpleExoPlayer != null) {
            HomeVideoHolder.simpleExoPlayer.stop();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        adapter.stopListening();
        if (HomeVideoHolder.simpleExoPlayer != null) {
            HomeVideoHolder.simpleExoPlayer.stop();

        }
```

I declared simpleExoplayer as a public static in HomeVideoHolder.

```
   public static PlayerView videoViewpath;
    public static SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
```

I also try stop, release, setPlayWhenReady(false) and seek to end of the video
to stop exoplayer.

but every method gave same result for me. They only stop last video of recyclerView.

please give me a solution for this problem......

my Adapter code...

```
        adapter=new FirestorePagingAdapter<HomeClass, HomeVideoHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeVideoHolder holder, int position, @NonNull HomeClass model) {
              
             
                    holder.setVideoView(getActivity(),model.getAd(),model.getpId(),model.getcUid(),model.getUid(),model.getPic(),model.getVideo(),model.getcT());
                
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public HomeVideoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new HomeVideoHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_video_item,parent,false));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                switch (state) {
                    case LOADING_INITIAL:
                        // The initial load has
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        break;
                    // ...
                    case LOADING_MORE:
                        // The adapter has started to load an additional page
                        vLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    // ...
                    case LOADED:
                        // The previous load (either initial or additional) completed
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        vLoadMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;

                    // ...
                    case FINISHED:
                        vLoadMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case ERROR:
                        // The previous load (either initial or additional) failed. Call
                        adapter.retry();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        // the retry() method in order to retry the load operation.
                        break;
                    // ...
                }
            }


        };
```

my viewHolder code....

```
 public void setVideoView(Activity activity,String ad, String pId, String cUid, String uid, String pic, String video, String cT) {
        final CircleImageView chanelProfile=view.findViewById(R.id.cPicH);
        final TextView chanelName=view.findViewById(R.id.cNameH);
        final TextView videoCaption=view.findViewById(R.id.vDesH);
        final ImageView videoThreeDot=view.findViewById(R.id.threeDotHome);

        Pkey=pId;
        user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        videoCaption.setText(cT);

        setPlayer(video);
}

    private void setPlayer(String video) {

        if (playCode.equals("true")) {

            LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(
                    new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
            );
            simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                    view.getContext(), trackSelector, loadControl
            );
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                    "Video"
            );
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(Video),
                    factory, extractorsFactory, null, null
            );
            videoViewpath.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
            videoViewpath.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {
                    super.onTimelineChanged(timeline, manifest, reason);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
                    super.onTracksChanged(trackGroups, trackSelections);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                    super.onLoadingChanged(isLoading);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                    super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState);
                    switch (playbackState) {

                        case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case Player.STATE_ENDED:

                            break;
                        case Player.STATE_IDLE:
                            break;
                        case Player.STATE_READY:
                            addViwes();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {
                    super.onRepeatModeChanged(repeatMode);

                }

                @Override
                public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {
                    super.onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(shuffleModeEnabled);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                    super.onPlayerError(error);
//                simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
//                simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {
                    super.onPositionDiscontinuity(reason);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {
                    super.onPlaybackParametersChanged(playbackParameters);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSeekProcessed() {
                    super.onSeekProcessed();
                }
            });

        }else {
                simpleExoPlayer.stop();
                simpleExoPlayer.release();
            simpleExoPlayer.clearVideoSurface();
            videoViewpath.setPlayer(null);
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. don't declare `PlayerView` and `SimpleExoPlayer` as `static`, this is wrong approach... you are keeping reference only to last video player instance and you want all of them to pause/stop all. every `HomeViewHolder` should keep only own player reference, `static` field keeps only one instance across all instances of reference-keeping class ("owner", `HomeViewHolder`)
2. remove all your `static` player stopping code from `onPause`, `onStop` and `onDestroy`, player instance (non-`static`) won't be accessible anyway
3. override `onViewDetachedFromWindow(HomeVideoHolder holder)` and/or `onViewRecycled(HomeVideoHolder holder)` method(s) in adapter, in this place pause/stop this one player instance attached to single `HomeVideoHolder`

let adapter stop every player when single item gets recycled/detached, not only when destroying `Activity`/`Fragment`. currently you have probably some memory leaks, as started players may stay in memory playing some video and you don't have reference to it (only to last one, `static` field as above) for releasing resources... when you destroy `RecyclerView` then adapter attached to it will recycle/destroy all currently existing `HomeViewPager`s, to be shure you may `recyclerView.setAdapter(null)` in `onDestroy` (before `super` call). also check how this pattern (recycling views) works with some `Log` calls in all overriden-able methods of [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) starting with `on...` (e.g. like mentioned in 3.)

Comment: You should be keeping one reference to `SimpleExoPlayer` in the main `Activity`  and pass that reference to where it's needed, otherwise you're likely to run into a [decoder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186395/video-player-error-com-google-android-exoplayer2-mediacodec-mediacodecrendererd)

Answer (score 1):

You should be keeping ONE instance of ExoPlayer. Create it in Activity and then pass to adapter through the constuctor. Here is my code:
Adapter:
`class VideoAdapter( private val mContext: Context,  val exoPlayer: ExoPlayer,  options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<VideoModel?>) :[...]`

```
exoPlayer
.also { exoPlayer ->
                styledPlayerView.player = exoPlayer
                exoPlayer.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
                styledPlayerView.setShowBuffering(StyledPlayerView.SHOW_BUFFERING_WHEN_PLAYING)
                styledPlayerView.useController = false
                exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE

            }
```

Activity:

```
private lateinit var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer [...]
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext())
        .build() [...]
videoAdapter = VideoAdapter(requireContext(), exoPlayer, options)
```

then in my Activities onStop() method:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    videoAdapter.stopListening()
    exoPlayer.release()
}
```